# How to get unique values with respective occurrence count from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a list which has repeating items and I want a list of the unique items with their frequency.

For example, I have `['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']`, and I want `[('a', 2), ('b', 3)]`.

Looking for a simple way to do this without looping twice.

Comment: Just so you know... the answer you accepted violates your "without looping twice" constraint. (I'm comment here so that you get notified :-).

Comment: Can you just clarify your question a little bit too? Are your items always grouped together? Or can they appear in any order in the list?

Comment: Yes, Tom. Although my question does not specify this - but in my particular situation, the values are coming sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your items are grouped (i.e. similar items come together in a bunch), the most efficient method to use is `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> [(g[0], len(list(g[1]))) for g in itertools.groupby(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'])]
[('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

Comment: @Tom: I'm aware of this limitation. When the items are grouped, however, `groupby` is the efficient and preferred approach

Comment: You should make that clear... notice the constraint in the question says "I have a list which has repeating items"... the list the OP gave was just an example. I don't think this solution is general enough. If the OP specified that the input list always had the elements grouped, I would agree.

Comment: @Tom: you're right - I've updated the answer (BTW I assumed from his "repeating items" that they're grouped)

Comment: Ok Eli... thanks for the update :-). I revoke my -1 because your answer is now more clear.

Comment: Is there a way to sort the resulting tuple list by count?

Comment: Yes! If `g` is the resulting object then `sorted(g, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Answer (score 74):

With Python 2.7+, you can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Otherwise, see [this counter receipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).

Under Python 2.7+:

```
from collections import Counter
input =  ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
c = Counter( input )

print( c.items() )
```

Output is:

> [('a', 2), ('b', 3)]

Answer (score 15):

```
>>> mylist=['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
>>> [ (i,mylist.count(i)) for i in set(mylist) ]
[('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to use a 3rd party library, NumPy offers a convenient solution. This is particularly efficient if your list contains only numeric data.

```
import numpy as np

L = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']

res = list(zip(*np.unique(L, return_counts=True)))

# [('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

To understand the syntax, note [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) here returns a tuple of unique values and counts:

```
uniq, counts = np.unique(L, return_counts=True)

print(uniq)    # ['a' 'b']
print(counts)  # [2 3]
```

See also: [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't a one-liner... but to me I like it because it's clear to me that we pass over the initial list of values once (instead of calling count on it):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in l:
...  d[i] += 1
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'b': 3})
>>> list(d.iteritems())
[('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

the "old school way".

```
>>> alist=['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
>>> d={}
>>> for i in alist:
...    if not d.has_key(i): d[i]=1  #also: if not i in d
...    else: d[i]+=1
...
>>> d
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be

```
mylist = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
mydict = {}
for i in mylist:
    if i in mydict: mydict[i] += 1
    else: mydict[i] = 1
```

then to get the list of tuples,

```
mytups = [(i, mydict[i]) for i in mydict]
```

This only goes over the list once, but it does have to traverse the dictionary once as well.  However, given that there are a lot of duplicates in the list, then the dictionary should be a lot smaller, hence faster to traverse.

Nevertheless, not a very pretty or concise bit of code, I'll admit.

Comment: This is identical in spirit to my solution... except defaultdict consolidates the first part (since you don't have to check for existence) and list(mydict.iteritems()) is shorter than the list comprehension.

Comment: `mytups = mydict.items()` is a simpler way to get the list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks @Paul and @Tom.  It seems like there is always a better way to do something in Python. :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution without hashing:

```
def lcount(lst):
   return reduce(lambda a, b: a[0:-1] + [(a[-1][0], a[-1][1]+1)] if a and b == a[-1][0] else a + [(b, 1)], lst, [])

>>> lcount([])
[]
>>> lcount(['a'])
[('a', 1)]
>>> lcount(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'])
[('a', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert any data structure into a pandas series s:

CODE:

```
for i in sort(s.value_counts().unique()):
  print i, (s.value_counts()==i).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

With help of pandas you can do like:

```
import pandas as pd
dict(pd.value_counts(my_list))
```