# How to get count of unique values in a list

Tags: python

Given a list:
a = ['ed', 'ed', 'ed', 'ash', 'ash, 'daph']

I want to iterate through the list and get the top 2 most used names. So I should expect a result of ['ed', 'ash']

[Update]

how to go about this without using a library

Comment: Are the equal elements always adjacent with each other?

Comment: @EugeneSh. no i just did it that way so it would be easy to understand, but if a sort function helps makes this more efficient then we can do that

Comment: Try: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique values with respective occurrence count from a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392929/how-to-get-unique-values-with-respective-occurrence-count-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) has a `most_common` method:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['ed', 'ed', 'ed', 'ash', 'ash', 'daph']

res = [item[0] for item in Counter(a).most_common(2)]

print(res)  # ['ed', 'ash']
```

with `most_common(2)` i get the 2 most common elements (and their multiplicity); the list-comprehension then removes the multiplicity and just removes the item in your original list.

Comment: @e_mam106 the collections module is part of the python standard library (since a very long time!). it hardly qualifyes as a 'library'. any (reasonably recent) python distribution will come with the collections module.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> c = Counter(a)

>>> c
Counter({'ed': 3, 'ash': 2, 'daph': 1})

# Sort items based on occurrence using most_common()
>>> c.most_common()
[('ed', 3), ('ash', 2), ('daph', 1)]

# Get top 2 using most_common(2)
>>> [item[0] for item in c.most_common(2)]
['ed', 'ash']

# Get top 2 using sorted
>>> sorted(c, key=c.get, reverse=True)[:2]
['ed', 'ash']
```