# How to get the sums of unique values with respective occurrence count from a list in Python?

Tags: python

With a list like this:

```py
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]
```

I would like to get the sums of each unique number `[1,2,3]` which is `[3, 4, 9]`. Using an approach from the related post [How to get unique values with respective occurrence count from a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392929/how-to-get-unique-values-with-respective-occurrence-count-from-a-list-in-python/2392948) I'm able to get the count of the occurence of each uniqe number using:

```py
L = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]
uniq, counts = np.unique(L, return_counts=True)
counts
```

Which gives the output `[3, 2, 3]`. With this, I'm able to get what I'm looking for using a cumbersome approach with an enumerated `For Loop` and some rather cryptic conditions:

```py
L = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]
elements = [3,2,3]
    
sums = []
index = 0
for i, e in enumerate(elements):
    if i == 0:
        sums.append(sum(L[0:e]))
        index = index + e
    else:
        sums.append(sum(L[index:index + e]))
        index = index + e
print(sums)
```

Which gives the desired output `[3, 4, 9]`. Does anyone know if it's possible to do the same thing a bit more elegantly?

Comment: I'd use *collections.Counter*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using Numpy, you can just multiply the results you already have from `np.unique`:

```
import numpy as np

L = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]    
uniq, counts = np.unique(L, return_counts=True)

uniq * counts
# array([3, 4, 9])
```

Comment: An old saying about a forest and some trees comes to mind... I really should have seen this....

Comment: To my defense, my real world issue is a combination of lists of strings and lists of numbers. My minimal example in the question should really have reflected that too,

Comment: @vestland yeah, that would make a solution a little less concise for sure.

Comment: But your approach is very likely the most concise answer to my question as it stands, so I'll gladly mark it as the accepted answer and try again later with a more precise description of my real world challenge.

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that the unique numbers are already grouped together:

```
from itertools import groupby

numbers = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

print([sum(group) for _, group in groupby(numbers)])
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 9]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Couter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) :

```
from collections import Counter

>>>L = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]
>>>[k*v for k,v in Counter(L).items()]
[3, 4, 9]
```

or in a dict:

```
>>>{k:k*v for k,v in Counter(L).items()}
{1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using `defaultdict` or a `dict`

**Using `defaultdict`:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
out = defaultdict(int)

for k in a :
    out[k] += k

print(list(out.values()))
# [3, 4, 9]
```

**Using `dict`:**

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
out = {}

for k in a:
    if k in out:
        out[k] += k
    else:
        out[k] = k

print(list(out.values()))
# [3, 4, 9]
```