# built-in range or numpy.arange: which is more efficient?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, range

When iterating over a large array with a range expression, should I use Python's built-in `range` function, or numpy's `arange` to get the best performance?

My reasoning so far:

`range` probably resorts to a native implementation and might be faster therefore. On the other hand, `arange` returns a full array, which occupies memory, so there might be an overhead. Python 3's range expression is a generator, which does not hold all the values in memory.

Comment: arange probably resorts to  ==> range probably resorts to.   Seems to be a typo.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

For large arrays, a vectorised numpy operation is the fastest. If you must loop, prefer `xrange`/`range` and avoid using `np.arange`.

In numpy you should use combinations of vectorized calculations, [ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) and [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to solve your problems as it runs at `C` speed.
Looping over numpy arrays is inefficient compared to this.

(Something like the worst thing you could do would be to iterate over the array with an index created with `range` or `np.arange` as the first sentence in your question suggests, but I'm not sure if you really mean that.)

```
import numpy as np
import sys

sys.version
# out: '2.7.3rc2 (default, Mar 22 2012, 04:35:15) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'
np.version.version
# out: '1.6.2'

size = int(1E6)

%timeit for x in range(size): x ** 2
# out: 10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop

%timeit for x in xrange(size): x ** 2
# out: 10 loops, best of 3: 88.9 ms per loop

# avoid this
%timeit for x in np.arange(size): x ** 2
#out: 1 loops, best of 3: 1.16 s per loop

# use this
%timeit np.arange(size) ** 2
#out: 100 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop
```

So for this case numpy is 4 times faster than using `xrange` if you do it right. Depending on your problem numpy can be much faster than a 4 or 5 times speed up.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993984/1301710) explain some more advantages of using numpy arrays instead of python lists for large data sets.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, there is no `xrange` in  *Python3.x*, and `range` is the same with `xrange` on it.

Comment: Also, I tested `for x in np.arange(size): x ** 2` which was faster than `for x in range(size): x ** 2` in `numpy==1.16.4` and  `python 3.6`

Answer (score 13):

First of all, as written by @bmu, *you should use combinations of vectorized calculations, ufuncs and indexing*. There are indeed some cases where explicit looping is required, but those are really rare.

If explicit loop is needed, with python 2.6 and 2.7, you should use *xrange* (see below). From what you say, in Python 3, *range* is the same as *xrange* (returns a generator). So maybe *range* is as good for you.

Now, you should try it yourself
(using timeit: - here the ipython "magic function"):

```
%timeit for i in range(1000000): pass
[out] 10 loops, best of 3: 63.6 ms per loop

%timeit for i in np.arange(1000000): pass
[out] 10 loops, best of 3: 158 ms per loop

%timeit for i in xrange(1000000): pass
[out] 10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ms per loop
```

Again, as mentioned above, most of the time it is possible to use numpy vector/array formula (or ufunc etc...) which run a c speed: **much faster**. This is what we could call "vector programming". It makes program easier to implement than C (and more readable) but almost as fast in the end.

Comment: There is a standard python 'timeit' module which allows to do the same without IPython. But it is just much more easy to use this magic function.

Comment: I fully agree, but the question was about "iterating over a large array". In some situation, it is not possible to use the numpy vectorized, ufunc or indexing. On example I encountered is to compute the eigenvectors of a list of matrices (>= 3x3)

Comment: I don't know if `np.arange` has been made more efficient since 2012, but it's main interest compared to the built-in `range` is that you can use float number as start:stop:step.

Comment: np.arange is useful when we have non integer step size

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `range` returns an iterator, `np.arange` returns a `np.array` with allocated memory (as OP already mentioned). To make both approaches comparable, we need to allocate a list for the iterator:

```
list(range(n))
```

When it comes to performance, it depends: For smaller (allocated) ranges, Python's `range(...)` is faster. However, `numpy`'s `np.arange(...)` scales nicely and outperforms for larger ranges:

[image]

Please find the benchmark code [here](https://gist.github.com/michaeldorner/c0fba1bc108fa230afd40d1d63d5df97). Run on MacBook Pro M1 with Python 3.11 and `numpy` 1.23.5

This question is very driven from a performance perspective (which is completely valid). However, I find the usability/maintainability viewpoint equally important: Importing `numpy` for creating just a range would be terrible. Also, vice-versa: A heavily `numpy`-driven code using `range` feels wrong.

Also keep in mind, that `np.arange` has a better support for non-integer step sizes.

To summarize: It depends. :-)