# Using np.arange to create list of coordinate pairs

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, numpy-ndarray, scientific-computing

I am trying to make a program faster and I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698858/built-in-range-or-numpy-arange-which-is-more-efficient) and I want to implement a solution that resembles the fourth case given in that question.

Here is the relevant part of the code I am using:

```
count = 0
hist_dat = np.zeros(r**2)
points = np.zeros((r**2, 2))
for a in range(r):
    for b in range(r):
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                hist_dat[count] += retval(a/r, (a+1)/r, data_a[i][j])*retval(b/r, (b+1)/r, data_b[i][j])/N
                points[count][0], points[count][1] = (a+0.5)/r, (b+0.5)/r
        count += 1
```

What this code does is generate the values of a normalized 2D histogram (with "r" divisions in each direction)  and the coordinates for those values as `numpy.ndarray`. 
As you can see in the other question linked, I am currently using the second worst possible solution and it takes several minutes to run.

For starters I want to change what the code is doing for the `points` array (I think that once I can see how that is done I could figure something out for `hist_dat`). Which is basically this:
[image: creation of the "points" numpy.ndarray]

In the particular case I am working on, both `A` and `B` are the same. So for example, it could be like going from `array([0, 0.5, 1])` to `array([[0,0], [0,0.5], [0,1], [0.5,0], [0.5,0.5], [0.5,1], [1,0], [1,0.5], [1,1]])`

Is there any method for `numpy.ndarray` or an operation with the `np.arange()` that does what the above diagram shows without requiring `for` loops?

Or is there any alternative that can do this as fast as what the linked post showed for the `np.arange()`?

Comment: What exactly does that diagram represent?

Comment: You have two `numpy.ndarray`'s and you combine them into one that contains all possible combinations. You can think of it as a Cartesian product of sets if you prefer. Also, it is what the code snippet above is doing.

Comment: By "set", you mean a mathematical set? In that case, is it possible for the sizes of the two arrays (`data_a` and `data_b`, right?), after being converted to sets, to be unequal (because they have different numbers of unique elements)?

Comment: No, they are the same size (in fact, in the case I am using they are exactly the same). For example, it could be like going from `array([0, 0.5, 1])` to `array([[0,0], [0,0.5], [0,1], [0.5,0], [0.5,0.5], [0.5,1], [1,0], [1,0.5], [1,1]])`. So it is like an array of "x" and "y" coordinates.

Comment: Does my answer address your problem? If it does, you might want to edit your question to focus on the abstract problem of, as you said, taking the Cartesian product of sets (although my answer actually assumes that the elements are unique, it is trivial to add a `np.unique` call)

Comment: Yes it does, but what is the `n_elements` in the `output` assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.c_` to combine the result of `np.repeat` and `np.tile`:

```
import numpy as np

start = 0.5
end = 5.5
step = 1.0

points = np.arange(start, end, step)  # [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
output = np.c_[np.repeat(points, n_elements), np.tile(points, n_elements)]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[0.5 0.5]
 [0.5 1.5]
 [0.5 2.5]
 [0.5 3.5]
 [0.5 4.5]
 [1.5 0.5]
 [1.5 1.5]
 [1.5 2.5]
 [1.5 3.5]
 [1.5 4.5]
 [2.5 0.5]
 [2.5 1.5]
 [2.5 2.5]
 [2.5 3.5]
 [2.5 4.5]
 [3.5 0.5]
 [3.5 1.5]
 [3.5 2.5]
 [3.5 3.5]
 [3.5 4.5]
 [4.5 0.5]
 [4.5 1.5]
 [4.5 2.5]
 [4.5 3.5]
 [4.5 4.5]]
```

Comment: What is the `n_elements`?

Comment: @SV In this case, it is merely an aid to generating input data with `np.arange`. If you have an input array, you would simply assign that to `points` and replace `n_elements` with `len(points)`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe `np.mgird` would help?

```py
import numpy as np
np.mgrid[0:2:.5,0:2:.5].reshape(2,4**2).T
```

Output:

```py
array([[0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5],
       [0. , 1. ],
       [0. , 1.5],
       [0.5, 0. ],
       [0.5, 0.5],
       [0.5, 1. ],
       [0.5, 1.5],
       [1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0.5],
       [1. , 1. ],
       [1. , 1.5],
       [1.5, 0. ],
       [1.5, 0.5],
       [1.5, 1. ],
       [1.5, 1.5]])
```