# Can numpy create n arrays by summing n elements in 1d array to each element of another 1d array?

Tags: python, numpy

Can't find a question/ answer that fits this exact criteria but if this is a duplicate question then I will delete it. Is there a numpy equivalent to the following code or is it better to just keep my code as is/ use xrange?

```
x = [i for i in range (50)]
y = [i for i in range (120)]

for i in x:
   foo = [i+z for z in y]
   print(foo)
```

This is a toy example but the the data set I am working with can range from something like this to 1000x the size in the example; I have tried `np.idter` but don't see much of a performance increase and as I gathered from [bmu's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698858/built-in-range-or-numpy-arange-which-is-more-efficient) using range to iterate over a numpy array is the worst. But I cannot see how ufunc and indexing can reproduce the same results as above which is my desired result.

Comment: `np.add.outer(x,y)`? Also read on [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic application of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0,5).reshape(5,1)
y = np.arange(0,12).reshape(1,12)

foos = x + y
print(foos)

[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
 [ 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]]
```

Obviously a binary operation like addition can't emit multiple arrays, but it can emit a higher dimensional array containing all the output arrays as rows or columns of that higher dimensional array.

As pointed out in comments, there is also a [generalization of the outer product](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy-ufunc-outer) which is functionally identical to the broadcasting approach I have shown.