# Minimal distance between elements in a vector

Tags: python, numpy

I need the minimal distance between elements of an array.

I did:

```
numpy.min(numpy.ediff1d(numpy.sort(x)))
```

Is there a better / more efficient / more elegant / faster way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want more elegant or more efficient?

Comment: ;-) Well, I think in my case I need the fastest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are after sheer speed, here are some timings:

```
In [13]: a = np.random.rand(1000)

In [14]: %timeit np.sort(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.9 us per loop

In [15]: %timeit np.ediff1d(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.2 us per loop

In [16]: %timeit np.diff(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.76 us per loop

In [17]: %timeit np.min(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.19 us per loop

In [18]: %timeit np.unique(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.8 us per loop
```

The timing of `unique` was in hopes that it would be comparably fast to `sort`, and you could break out early without the calls to `diff` and `min` if the length of the unique array was shorter than the array itself (as that would mean your answer was `0`). But the overhead of `unique` is more than any gain to be made.

So it seems the only potential improvement I can offer is replacing `ediff1d` with `diff`:

```
In [19]: %timeit np.min(np.diff(np.sort(a)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.7 us per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.min(np.ediff1d(np.sort(a)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.1 us per loop
```

Comment: Interresting. I was expecting `ediff1d` to be faster than `diff`, since it is for 1d arrays, but apparently `diff` is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach is definitely optimal. By sorting first, you're reducing the space in between each element and `ediff1d` will return a difference array. Here's a suggestion:

Since we know that the difference must be positive since we have an ascending-order sort, we can implement `ediff1d` manually and include a break where the difference is zero. That way, if you have the sorted array `x`:

`[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... , n]`

Rather than going through n elements, your `ediff1d` function breaks early and covers only the first two elements, returning `[0]`. This also reduces the size of the difference array, reducing the amount of iterations required by your `min` call.

Here is an example without the use of numpy:

```
x = [1, 12, 3, 8, 4, 1, 4, 9, 1, 29, 210, 313, 12]

def ediff1d_custom(x):
    darr = []

    for i in xrange(len(x)):
        if i != len(x) - 1:
            diff = x[i + 1] - x[i]
            darr.append(diff)

            if diff == 0:
                break

    return darr

print min(ediff1d_custom(sorted(x))) # prints 0
```

Comment: Interesting, but overkill and not exactly what I need. My need is for values inside a single 1d array.

Comment: Unless the expected min actually is zero, this will be significantly slower than OP's existing solution.

Comment: How is that? Is it because numpy is precompiled?

Comment: @DanielLi Pretty much, and the arrays are (usually) in contiguous memory instead of dynamic lists.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/993984/1730674

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    min(x[i+1]-x[i] for i in xrange(0, len(x)-1))
except ValueError:
    print 'Array contains less than two values.'
```

Comment: `x` must still be sorted before you can do this, since this is basically just non-numpy `min(ediff1d(x))`