# MemoryError in Python while using cKDTree().query_ball_tree

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

I have large 2D arrays with unsorted (X,Y) points, for which I need to know which points are in close proximity to each other (nearest-neighbor lookup). I have used cKDTree and query_ball_tree with succes for arrays with around 500,000 (X,Y) points. However, when I try the same algorithm for datasets of more than 1,000,000 points, query_ball_tree results in a MemoryError.

I use 64-bit Windows with 16Gb of internal memory, and have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python and the extension modules (scipy and numpy).

```
def Construct_SearchTree(AllXyPoints):
    KDsearch = cKDTree(AllXyPoints)  
    return KDsearch.query_ball_tree(KDsearch, Maxdist)
```

My questions:

1) does anybody know of an alternative to cKDTree / query_ball_tree that consumes less memory? Speed is less important in this case that memory usage.

2) I hoped that switching from 32-bit to 64-bit python & extensions would solve the MemoryError. What could be the reason that it didn't?

Thanks for your incoming help and advice.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced a `MemoryError` with SciPy's `cKDTree` during construction and scikit-learn's `KDTree` when calling `.query_radius()`.  I found that [Scikit-learn's](http://scikit-learn.org/) [`BallTree`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) was more memory efficient, and using a `BallTree` solved the issue for me.  I've tested `BallTree` with 1 million data points on my 64-bit system. It still consumes all my available memory (12GB) and some swap space, but I don't get a `MemoryError`.

Queries on a `BallTree` will not be as fast as a `KDTree` since your data is 2D, and `BallTree`s are slower than `KDTree`s when d <= 3 (see explanation [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2017sp/lectures/lecturenote16.html)). However, given that `cKDtree` and scikit-learn's `KDTree` both raise `MemorError`s (on my system, anyway), the simplest solution is to use a `BallTree`.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

max_dist = .1
points = np.random.normal(size=2000000).reshape(1000000, 2) #1 million points
ball_tree = BallTree(points)

neighbors = ball_tree.query_radius(points, max_dist)
```

Depending on your `Maxdist`, the returned result can consume a lot of memory (up to O(n^2)), but scikit-learn's `BallTree.query_radius()` returns an `np.array` of `np.array`s rather than a `list` of `list`s so it should save you some memory there (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/994010/1940479) for an explanation).

Comment: A Ball-tree is also not a KD-tree (and the effects are unmentioned; despite saying it's working with some given dimensions). But i'm also recommending sklearn for these data-stuctures.

Comment: @sascha, I've updated my answer. Apart from performance, did you have other effects in mind?

Comment: @JaminSore Rather than querying the nearest neighbors within a ***single list*** Is it possible to use the ball tree method to compute the ***nearest distance neighbours for coordinates between two nested lists***: `a` and `b`, where `a dimension = 1000,2`, `b dimension = 2000,2`: e.g. `a=[ [1.2, 1.3], [6.5, 10] ... ]` and `b= [ [11,1.2] , [9.6, 8]... ]`. I've done this using `scipy.spatial.kdtree` by doing: `tree = spatial.KDTree(a)` and `closest_distance, closest_index = tree.query(b, k=1, p=2)`. But I'm not sure is possible with `ball tree`. Is?

Comment: @Chuck Yes. From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.query) `query()` takes an *array-like* (read `list`, `numpy.array` or anything that quacks like an array) as the first argument. In my example, the `points` I passed to `query_radius()` did not have to be the same points used in construction--the same goes for `query()`