# How to get a boolean array from applying criteria to an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, boolean

Someone suggested that in python it is possible to get a boolean array with criteria applied to certain numerical array.

Say I have
`array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
I want to apply the criteria
`x>2 & x<5`
so that the resulting array would be something like
`>>> [F, F, T, T, F]`

I wonder if this is possible and how should I get there, thanks!
(please just ignore any syntax mistake above as I'm new to python, sorry for any potential confusion those might cause)

Comment: Are you working in NumPy?

Comment: @sshashank124 why say that? I'm only asking because I don't know how to program, I can certainly pay someone to work for me but then it would be like cheating. Why is a question like this sounds so rude to you?

Comment: By the way in python you can write this as `2 < x < 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is called a `list` in `python`. `array` usually means `numpy.array` here.

In `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
(arr>2)&(arr<5)
```

Or without `numpy`:

```
In [5]:

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2<item<5 for item in array1]
Out[5]:
[False, False, True, True, False]
In [11]:

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
['T' if 2<item<5 else 'F' for item in array1]
Out[11]:
['F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'F']
```

Using `lambda` with `map` is usually the recipe for slow code:

```
In [6]:

%timeit list(map(lambda x: x > 2 and x < 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.63 µs per loop
In [7]:

%timeit [2<item<5 for item in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4 µs per loop
```

Comment: Could you plz tell me for my purpose is there any difference between using an array and a list? It seemed to me like only an array could do the work here, I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: @LilMuji: There's plenty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists

Comment: You could always just do `[2<item<5 for item in array1]`

Comment: @LilMuji, `array` usually mean other things in `python`, say, `array` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html or `numpy.array`, not thing magic, just a terminology.

Comment: @SukritKalra, maybe OP wants `'T'` and `'F'`s. Who knows.

Comment: @CTZhu what do you mean by slow code? it runs slow with a large amount of data? :( My goal is actually to apply this boolean list to something else in order to select elements at certain position. Say with `[False, False, True, True, False]` I want to turn `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]` into `[4, 6]` or `[0, 0, 4, 6, 0]`, that's why I was trying to get the boolean list first... Anyway thanks a lot

Comment: Slow code was referring to that `lambda` `map` solution, never mind on that. To get `[4,6]`, do: `[item for item in array1 if 2<item<5]`. Please look up `python` `list` comprehension. Cheers.

Comment: @CTZhu I'm actually applying that position info (which I get from list1) onto a different list(list2) through the boolean list.. so I guess `[item for item in array1 if 2<item<5]` won't work

Comment: `[item2 for item1,item2 in zip(array1, array2) if 2<item1<5]`, if the other `list` is `array2`.

Comment: @CTZhu it worked!! <3 this is way too cool