# merge 2D array into a list python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

What I want to do is to turn a 2D array like this:

> np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
>                        [ 1,  5,  6,  7]])

into this (a list with all numbers in):

> [0,1,2,3,1,5,6,7]

is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: -1 https://www.google.co.in/search?q=flatten+a+2d+numpy+array

Comment: do you really want a list or just `np.flatten`??

Comment: +1: googling "flatten" only works if you know to use the word "flatten", but if you know that, you already know the answer.

Comment: Padraic Cunningham is right.  You usually want to avoid lessening the nature of your datatypes.  If you have a `numpy.array` to begin with, keep it as a `numpy.array`.  Otherwise, it could cause errors/confusion when someone, thinking that it is still a `numpy.array`, tries to use it as one.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = np.array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3], [ 1, 5, 6, 7]])    

list(x.flat)    # if you want a list
#  [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7]

x.flatten()  # if you want a numpy array
#   array([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7])
```

It's unclear to me whether you want a list or numpy array, but they are both easy to get (although I assume you want a list since you tagged this question with `list`).  It's reasonable to pick whichever you want or is most useful to you.

For many uses, [numpy has significant advantages over lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists), but there are also times that lists work better.  For example, in many constructions, one gets items one at a time and doesn't know ahead of time the size of the resulting output array, and in this case it can make sense to build a list using `append` and then convert it to a numpy array to take an FFT.

There are other approaches to converting between lists and numpy arrays.  When you have the need to do things to be different (eg, faster), be sure to look at the documentation or ask back here.

Comment: definitely the best as OP is using numpy

Comment: `x.reshape(-1)` is another way of producing the 1d array.  Tack on `.tolist()` to make it a list.

Comment: An interesting point is that `flatten` returns a copy, `ravel` (and `reshape`) only does so if necessary.  In some cases that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'raw' Python I was writing a simple player vs computer Tic Tac Toe game. The board was a 2D array of cells numbered 1 - 9. Player would select a cell to put their 'X' in. Computer would randomly select a cell to put their 'O' in from the remaining available cells. I wanted to transform the 2D board in a 1D list. Here's how.

```
>>> board=[["1","2","O"],["4","X","6"],["X","O","9"]]
>>> [ board[row][col] for row in range(len(board)) for col in range(len(board[row])) if board[row][col] != "X" if board[row][col] != "O" ]
['1', '2', '4', '6', '9']
>>>
```