# Out of memory with Python but OK with Matlab while displaying the same 2D data as image

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I have a 2D array to display as image (it is 500 by 20 000).

Python:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    

spect_data = np.loadtxt('some_data.txt') 

plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
plt.imshow(spect_data,aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Matlab:

```
spect_data=load('some_data.txt');
imagesc(spect_data)
```

Here's the error I get (sorry I wasn't clear about my problem the first time):

> Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py",
>   line 339, in **call**
>       return printer(obj)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py",
>   line 228, in 
>       png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py",
>   line 119, in print_figure
>       fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py",
>   line 2180, in print_figure
>       **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py",
>   line 527, in print_png
>       FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py",
>   line 474, in draw
>       self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line
>   61, in draw_wrapper
>       draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line
>   1159, in draw
>       func(*args)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line
>   61, in draw_wrapper
>       draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py",
>   line 2324, in draw
>       a.draw(renderer)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line
>   61, in draw_wrapper
>       draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py",
>   line 389, in draw
>       im = self.make_image(renderer.get_image_magnification())
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py",
>   line 624, in make_image
>       transformed_viewLim)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py",
>   line 238, in _get_unsampled_image
>       x = (x * 255).astype(np.uint8)
>
> MemoryError

Comment: maybe include MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Their functions may not be stored in memory. It may be using [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: Maybe use a Numpy array `results` instead of a list. [That will save you space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/994010/1586200).

Comment: What is the full backtrace of the error message?  Without knowing exactly where the memory error is occurring it is impossible to help.

Comment: Your code runs fine on my linux machine. Maybe it's something to do with anaconda or windows, both of which I don't use. So someone else will be better able to help. Is anaconda up to date? Have you tried a different python distribution? Have you tried `imshow` on other (smaller) data?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem, but you seem to have the data in memory several times - as a numpy array, as a list of floats, and as a list of strings.

If you only need the numpy array, you could use

```
np.loadtxt
```

or

```
np.fromfile
```

if you need more control over how the data is read.

This assumes (you do not specify) that the data is in an ASCII file.
For a more specific answer, you should post your code so people can see what you are doing and where the problem might be.

Comment: I changed the way the data is loaded (by the way, thanks, it's very useful to know), but still MemoryError...

Comment: @Sylwia Please update your original post with the new version.

Comment: `imshow` seems to be fine with data of your size. I tried with `a=np.random.normal(size=(500,20000))`, `imshow(a)` with the expected result of seing a plot of the above random data. This is python3.5.2 or 2.7.12 running in ipython. Old laptop with 3GB RAM, but lots of other stuff running as well. What's the exact error you are getting?