# Computing Jaccard Similarity in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, data-mining

I have 20,000 documents that I want to compute the true Jaccard similarity for, so that I can later check how accurately MinWise hashing approximates it.

Each document is represented as a column in a numpy matrix, where each row is a word that either appears in document (entry=1) or does not (entry = 0). There are ~600 words (rows).

So for example column 1 would be [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0], which means words 1,7,11 appeared in it and no others.

Is there a more efficient way to compute the similarity besides my element-wise comparison approach? I don't see how I could use sets to improve the speed since the sets just become (0,1), but as it stands the code is impossibly slow.

```
import numpy as np

#load file into python
rawdata = np.loadtxt("myfile.csv",delimiter="\t")
#Convert the documents from rows to columns
rawdata = np.transpose(rawdata)
#compute true jacard similarity
ndocs = rawdata.shape[1]
nwords = rawdata.shape[0]
tru_sim = np.zeros((ndocs,ndocs))

#computes jaccard similarity of 2 documents
def jaccard(c1, c2):
    n11 = sum((c1==1)&(c2==1))
    n00 = sum((c1==0)&(c2==0))
    jac = n11 / (nfeats-n00)
    return (jac)

for i in range(0,ndocs):
    tru_sim[i,i]=1
    for j in range(i+1,ndocs):
        tru_sim[i,j] = jaccard(rawdata[:,i],rawdata[:,j])
```

Comment: Have you seen [scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard.html)?  Use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) with `metric='jaccard'`. Subtract that from 1 to get the similarity.

Comment: Another good suggestion, especially since you can use spicpy.spatial.distance.squareform to get the matrix back easily . https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
# Get the row, col indices that are to be set in output array        
r,c = np.tril_indices(ndocs,-1)

# Use those indicees to slice out respective columns 
p1 = rawdata[:,c]
p2 = rawdata[:,r]

# Perform n11 and n00 vectorized computations across all indexed columns
n11v = ((p1==1) & (p2==1)).sum(0)
n00v = ((p1==0) & (p2==0)).sum(0)

# Finally, setup output array and set final division computations
out = np.eye(ndocs)
out[c,r] = n11v / (nfeats-n00v)
```

Alternative way to compute `n11v` and `n00v` with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
n11v = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',(p1==1),(p2==1).astype(int))
n00v = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',(p1==0),(p2==0).astype(int))
```

If `rawdata` consists of `0s` and `1s` only, a simpler way to get them would be -

```
n11v = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',p1,p2)
n00v = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',1-p1,1-p2)
```

**Benchmarking**

Function definitions -

```
def original_app(rawdata, ndocs, nfeats):
    tru_sim = np.zeros((ndocs,ndocs))
    for i in range(0,ndocs):
        tru_sim[i,i]=1
        for j in range(i+1,ndocs):
            tru_sim[i,j] = jaccard(rawdata[:,i],rawdata[:,j])
    return tru_sim

def vectorized_app(rawdata, ndocs, nfeats):
    r,c = np.tril_indices(ndocs,-1)
    p1 = rawdata[:,c]
    p2 = rawdata[:,r]
    n11v = ((p1==1) & (p2==1)).sum(0)
    n00v = ((p1==0) & (p2==0)).sum(0)
    out = np.eye(ndocs)
    out[c,r] = n11v / (nfeats-n00v)
    return out
```

Verification and timings -

```
In [6]: # Setup inputs
   ...: rawdata = (np.random.rand(20,10000)>0.2).astype(int)
   ...: rawdata = np.transpose(rawdata)
   ...: ndocs = rawdata.shape[1]
   ...: nwords = rawdata.shape[0]
   ...: nfeats = 5
   ...: 

In [7]: # Verify results
   ...: out1 = original_app(rawdata, ndocs, nfeats)
   ...: out2 = vectorized_app(rawdata, ndocs, nfeats)
   ...: print np.allclose(out1,out2)
   ...: 
True

In [8]: %timeit original_app(rawdata, ndocs, nfeats)
1 loops, best of 3: 8.72 s per loop

In [9]: %timeit vectorized_app(rawdata, ndocs, nfeats)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.6 ms per loop
```

Some magical **`300x+`** speedup there!

**So, why is it so fast?** Well, there are lots of factors involved, most important one being the fact NumPy arrays are built for performance and optimized for vectorized computations. With the proposed approach we are harnessing it quite well and thus seeing such speedups.

Here's one [`related Q&A`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists) that talk about these performance criteria in detail.

Comment: My data does consist of only 1s and 0s.  Can you explain why this is more computationally efficient than the approach I used?

Comment: @Magic8ball Added runtime test and some comments on why it's efficient. Check it out!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Right now I'm getting a MemoryError on the step p1 = rawdata[:,c] , since it is an array with about 232 million entries, so I'm not sure if this particular code is scalable to my project but the ideas are helpful.

Comment: @Magic8ball Ah wow! So, without falling back to your loopy approach, you can work in the middle-ground by processing data in chunks, if you can get through the first step of : `r,c = np.tril_indices(ndocs,-1)`. Then, use chunks of indices from `r` and `c` and use a loop to process chunks.

Comment: Mind including scipy.spatial.distance.pdist in your benchmark as well?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Well with `pdist` version I am not sure how to incorporate `nfeats` as a param. But, I tried without the param and `pdist` had `11.2 ms per loop` against `26.8 ms per loop` for the vectorized one. So, a definite improvement there, if only we could figure out how to use `pdist` with that param.

Comment: What's `n_feats`, and why do you need it? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index Also, in your benchmark, doesn't this say "vectorized" is 3x *slower*?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I am not familiar with Jaccard index, but all I know is OP has that as a param :) `""vectorized" is 3x slower? "`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the unit. 8 ms rather than 8 s would have been faster. But nevertheless, `nfeats` should be `nwords`. Also beware that your benchmark may be misleading when nfeats is really large, and really sparse.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse is correct, I used "nfeats" (number of features) but nwords is clearer.

Comment: @Magic8ball So, `nfeats = nowrds`?

Comment: @Divakar Yes nfeats = nwords.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse is correct. This doesn't scale with features due to huge memory consumption.

Comment: Memory issues? For datasets on 100k range or more, try Minhash LSH for an approximation of Jaccard: https://github.com/mattilyra/LSH/blob/master/examples/Introduction.ipynb

Answer (score 3):

To compute Jaccard, use:

```
def jaccard(x,y):
  x = np.asarray(x, np.bool) # Not necessary, if you keep your data
  y = np.asarray(y, np.bool) # in a boolean array already!
  return np.double(np.bitwise_and(x, y).sum()) / np.double(np.bitwise_or(x, y).sum())

print jaccard([1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1])
>>> 0.33333333333333331
```