# Fastest object to iterate a chars in a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

I'm iterating through a list of words to find the most frequently used character between words (i.e. in list `[hello, hank]`, `'h'` counts as appearing twice while `'l'` counts as appearing once.). A python list works fine, but I'm also looking into NumPy (dtype array?), and Pandas. It looks like Numpy may be the way to go, but are there other packages to consider? How else can I make this function faster?

Code in Question:

```
def mostCommon(guessed, li):
    count = Counter()
    for words in li:
          for letters in set(words):
              count[letters]+=1
    return count.most_common()[:10]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "most frequent unique character"? And include some example input and output data

Comment: @Chris_Rands Edited with an example, lmk if you need more.

Comment: So you only want the most frequent character or the frequency of all the characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a NumPy approach using its `views-concept` -

```
def tabulate_occurrences(a):           # Case sensitive
    chars = np.asarray(a).view('S1')
    valid_chars = chars[chars!='']
    unqchars, count = np.unique(valid_chars, return_counts=1)
    return pd.DataFrame({'char':unqchars, 'count':count})

def topNchars(a, N = 10):               # Case insensitive
    s = np.core.defchararray.lower(a).view('uint8')
    unq, count = np.unique(s[s!=0], return_counts=1)
    sidx = count.argsort()[-N:][::-1]
    h = unq[sidx]
    return [str(unichr(i)) for i in h]
```

Sample run -

```
In [322]: a = ['er', 'IS' , 'you', 'Is', 'is', 'er', 'IS']

In [323]: tabulate_occurrences(a) # Case sensitive
Out[323]: 
  char  count
0    I      3
1    S      2
2    e      2
3    i      1
4    o      1
5    r      2
6    s      2
7    u      1
8    y      1

In [533]: topNchars(a, 5)         # Case insensitive
Out[533]: ['s', 'i', 'r', 'e', 'y']

In [534]: topNchars(a, 10)        # Case insensitive
Out[534]: ['s', 'i', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'u', 'o']
```

Comment: Hm. I just timed this, looks slower than a regular list solution.

Comment: @ZtoYi Do you need the actual count of occurrences of  top 10 characters too or just want to find those characters only?

Comment: Just the characters will be fine.

Comment: @ZtoYi Also, are you only dealing with lower case letters?

Comment: lower case and upper case should count as the same letter.

Comment: @ZtoYi Try the latest one named : `topNchars`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133114/discussion-between-ztoyi-and-divakar).

Answer (score 3):

***option 1***

```
def pir1(li):
    sets = [set(s) for s in li]
    ul = np.array(list(set.union(*sets)))
    us = np.apply_along_axis(set, 1, ul[:, None])
    c = (sets >= us).sum(1)
    a = c.argsort()[:-11:-1]
    return ul[a]
```

***option 2***

```
def pir2(li):
    return Counter(chain.from_iterable([list(set(i)) for i in li])).most_common(10)
```

---

Assume a list of words `li`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase

li = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), (1000, 10))
).sum(1).tolist()
```

---

Including Divakar's and OP's functions

```
def tabulate_occurrences(a):
    chars = np.asarray(a).view('S1')
    valid_chars = chars[chars!='']
    unqchars, count = np.unique(valid_chars, return_counts=1)
    return pd.DataFrame({'char':unqchars, 'count':count})

def topNchars(a, N = 10):
    s = np.core.defchararray.lower(a).view('uint8')
    unq, count = np.unique(s[s!=0], return_counts=1)
    sidx = count.argsort()[-N:][::-1]
    h = unq[sidx]
    return [str(chr(i)) for i in h]

def mostCommon(li):
    count = Counter()
    for words in li:
          for letters in set(words):
              count[letters]+=1
    return count.most_common()[:10]
```

---

***testing***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase
from timeit import timeit

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.RangeIndex(5, 405, 5, name='No. Words'),
    columns=pd.Index('pir1 pir2 mostCommon topNchars'.split(), name='Method'),
)

np.random.seed([3,1415])
for i in results.index:    
    li = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), (i, 10))
    ).sum(1).tolist()
    for j in results.columns:
        v = timeit(
            '{}(li)'.format(j),
            'from __main__ import {}, li'.format(j),
            number=100
        )
        results.set_value(i, j, v)

ax = results.plot(title='Time Testing')
ax.set_ylabel('Time of 100 iterations')
```

[image]

Comment: So, the final o/p would be that one max occuring char, right?

Comment: @Divakar based on their code, they wanted top 10.  Also comment on other answer "what if I wanted next most frequent?"

Comment: @piRSquared I'm trying to time these options as you spit them out! Thanks! Can you sort them in a way that I can get the top 10 chars (ties don't matter)? Thanks.

Comment: @ZtoYi I've gotta run.  Hopefully I was helpful.  Good luck.

Comment: Good options but I don't think (as currently implemented) these fill the requirement of only counting each letter once per word

Comment: @piRSquared option1 does not take into account that letters that repeat in a word should not be counted twice.

Comment: @Chris_Rands / ZtoYi yep, I see that.  working on it

Comment: @piRSquared Option1 seems to be slower than the original solution I posted, why do you think it is a better implementation? As for options 2/3, I don't know much about pandas/numpy so I'm trying to figure out how to get just the list of chars at the moment, then I'll test it and let you know the speedups!

Comment: @ZtoYi the old answer said "better".  I intentionally left that off for now.  I'm continuing to try to optimize these

Comment: @piRSquared Very nice graph, summarizes the results :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only want the most frequent character, where each character only counts a once per word:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = ['hello', 'hank']
>>> chars = list(chain.from_iterable([list(set(word)) for word in l]))
>>> max(chars, key=chars.count)
'h'
```

Using `max` with `list.count` can be a lot faster than using `Counter` due to the C level implementation.

Comment: what if I wanted the next most frequent letter?

Comment: @ZtoYi Then you may not want to use this approach; although it's still possible, you could use `heapq` or sort the list of `chars`, but both will add quite a bit of overhead

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is very fast already, and runs in `O(n)`. The only real improvement opportunity that I see would be to parallelize this process by splitting `li` into multiple parts.

Comment: It's an O(n) problem, but was wondering if using a different object might help the speed. (i.e. this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Python solution that uniqueifies each string, joins the sets, then counts the results (Using Divakar's example list)

```
>>> li=['er', 'IS' , 'you', 'Is', 'is', 'er', 'IS']
>>> Counter(e for sl in map(list, map(set, li)) for e in sl)
Counter({'I': 3, 'e': 2, 's': 2, 'S': 2, 'r': 2, 'o': 1, 'i': 1, 'u': 1, 'y': 1})
```

If you want upper and lower case to be counted as the same letter:

```
>>> Counter(e for sl in map(list, map(set, [s.lower() for s in li])) for e in sl)
Counter({'i': 4, 's': 4, 'e': 2, 'r': 2, 'o': 1, 'u': 1, 'y': 1})
```

Now let's time that:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def dawg(li):
    return Counter(e for sl in map(list, map(set, li)) for e in sl)

def nump(a):
    chars = np.asarray(a).view('S1')
    valid_chars = chars[chars!='']
    unqchars, count = np.unique(valid_chars, return_counts=1)
    return pd.DataFrame({'char':unqchars, 'count':count})

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit  
    li=['er', 'IS' , 'you', 'Is', 'is', 'er', 'IS'] 
    for f in (dawg, nump):
        print("   ",f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f(li)", setup="from __main__ import f, li", number=100) )
```

Results:

```
dawg 0.00134205818176
nump 0.0347728729248
```

The Python solution is significantly faster in this case

Answer (score -1):

Just do

```
counter = Counter(''.join(li))
most_common = counter.most_common()
```

and you're done