# Why is processing a random list so much faster than processing an ordered list?

Tags: python, performance

I was trying to improve the performance of the `func` function and I found that a simple change in how the `aX` list is generated improves the performance quite a bit:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

def func(a, b):
    return [_ for _ in a if _ not in b]

Na, Nb = 10000, 5000
b = list(np.random.randint(1000, size=Nb))

# Ordered list of Na integers
a1 = [_ for _ in range(Na)]
# Random list of Na integers
a2 = list(np.random.randint(Na, size=Na))
# Ordered list of Na integers generated with numpy
a3 = list(np.arange(Na))

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
ab1 = func(a1, b)
abt1 = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("Time ab1", abt1)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
ab2 = func(a2, b)
abt2 = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("Time ab2", abt2)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
ab3 = func(a3, b)
abt3 = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("Time ab3", abt3)

print("Ratio 1/2:", abt1 / abt2)
print("Ratio 1/3:", abt1 / abt3)
```

In Python 2.7.13 this results in:

```
('Time ab1', 5.296088933944702)
('Time ab2', 1.5520200729370117)
('Time ab3', 1.5581469535827637)
('Ratio 1/2:', 3.412384302428827)
('Ratio 1/3:', 3.3989662667998095)
```

In Python 3.5.2 the difference is even larger:

```
Time ab1 6.758207322000089
Time ab2 1.5693355060011527
Time ab3 1.5148192759988888
Ratio 1/2: 4.306413317073784
Ratio 1/3: 4.461395117608107
```

I need to process an *ordered list integers* (i.e: `a1` or `a3`), so my question is:

Why is the random list processed so much faster than the ordered list **not** generated with `numpy`?

Comment: This might be a silly question but can you not *re-order* or *order* the `list` **after** you are done processing it?

Comment: Is this a fair test? The max value in the list `a1` will be 10000 (the length of the list) where as the max value in the list `a2` will be 1000 as it would be a random number between 0 and 1000 thus replacing `a1 = [_ for _ in range(Na)]` with `a1 = [_//10 for _ in range(Na)]` gives a ratio of 4.6 still unsure why its faster. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding this.

Comment: @Alessi42 makes a valid point. I'll edit the question to fix this difference. Thank you!

Comment: Since the ordered list generated with `numpy` (`a3`) is processed as fast as the random list (`a2`), this appears to be simply a matter of "`numpy` is just faster".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `b`, `a2`, and `a3` lists are lists of NumPy scalars, while your `a1` list is a list of ordinary Python ints. Comparing NumPy scalars to ordinary Python scalars requires a *lot* of extra type checking and coercion, so the `func(a1, b)` test, which needs to compare NumPy scalars to ordinary Python scalars, performs slowest.

If you make `b` a list of Python ints (by calling the [`tolist` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) instead of the `list` function), the time difference is reversed.

You may want to consider using Python `set`s or NumPy's [set-like operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.set.html) to perform your task.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists) numpy arrays are much faster than python lists. This is why the numpy arrays seem faster as you are still using a numpy array when you call the `list()` function.

Using the numpy [`.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) function converts a NumPy array to regular Python objects all the way down (as user2357112 pointed out) and the performance differences disappear, see:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

def func(a, b):
    return [_ for _ in a if _ not in b]

Na, Nb = 10000, 5000
b = list(np.random.randint(Na, size=Nb)) # len: 5000, max: 9999

# Ordered list of Na integers
a1 = [_ for _ in range(Na)] # len: 10000, max: 9999
# Random list of Na integers
a2 = np.random.randint(Na, size=Na).tolist() # len: 10000, max: 9999
# Ordered list of Na integers generated with numpy
a3 = np.arange(Na).tolist()

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
ab1 = func(a1, b)
abt1 = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("Time ab1", abt1)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
ab2 = func(a2, b)
abt2 = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("Time ab2", abt2)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
ab3 = func(a3, b)
abt3 = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("Time ab3", abt3)

print("Ratio 1/2:", abt1 / abt2)
print("Ratio 1/3:", abt1 / abt3)

#Time ab1 4.622085004015502
#Time ab2 4.598610720638726
#Time ab3 4.63976530848255
#Ratio 1/2: 1.005104646773301
#Ratio 1/3: 0.9961893968139456
```

Hopefully this answers your first question!

Comment: can you give a source for `This is why the numpy arrays seem faster as you are still using a numpy array when you call the list() function`?

Comment: I have now included the docs for `ndarray.tolist()` but I can't seem to find a reference as to why `list()` doesn't do the same I assumed that if they added a function for it, it must not do it by default

Comment: `list` does build a list. `tolist` converts a NumPy array to regular Python objects all the way down, building a nested list for multidimensional arrays and converting all scalars to ordinary Python scalars.