# Mean of a series contained within a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, series

The following DataFrame (df) has 3 columns : `Event`, `Counts` and `Length` where the `Counts` column contains series of numbers. I would like to estimate the mean of each `Counts` row and display it on a fourth one.

```
df = 
Event                                                 Counts Length  
0     [111240.0, 110530.0, 108540.0, 108540.0, 10838...       5                                                      
7     [117240.0, 119160.0, 120160.0, 121950.0, 12195...       6
13    [180420.0, 180420.0, 183840.0, 183840.0, 18384...       6
16    [160260.0, 159430.0, 159430.0, 157720.0, 15955...      14
```

I have tested the following expression without success.

```
 df['mean'] = df['counts'].mean(axis = 1)
```

and other variations based on this line.

If I understand correctly, the problem due to the fact that the `Count` column contains more than one element.

I appreciate your help for this apparently easy problem.

Comment: try this:  df['mean'] = df.Counts.map(lambda counts:pd.Series(counts).mean())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Numpy assuming they are all of the same length

```
df['Mean'] = np.mean(df['Counts'].tolist(), axis=1)
df

   Event                                           Counts  Length      Mean
0      0  [111240.0, 110530.0, 108540.0, 108540.0, 10838]       5   89937.6
1      7  [117240.0, 119160.0, 120160.0, 121950.0, 12195]       6   98141.0
2     13  [180420.0, 180420.0, 183840.0, 183840.0, 18384]       6  149380.8
3     16  [160260.0, 159430.0, 159430.0, 157720.0, 15955]      14  130559.0
```

Otherwise

```
df['Mean'] = df['Counts'].apply(np.mean)
df

   Event                                           Counts  Length      Mean
0      0  [111240.0, 110530.0, 108540.0, 108540.0, 10838]       5   89937.6
1      7  [117240.0, 119160.0, 120160.0, 121950.0, 12195]       6   98141.0
2     13  [180420.0, 180420.0, 183840.0, 183840.0, 18384]       6  149380.8
3     16  [160260.0, 159430.0, 159430.0, 157720.0, 15955]      14  130559.0
```

Comment: The first option you proposed gave me this error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.  But the second option worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I'm not always trying to optimize OP's code.  Sometimes (especially when they don't ask for it) I give them what seems intuitive.

Comment: @The_rookie that is almost certainly because your list/arrays in `Counts` are not of the same length and won't fit into a rectangular array.  Which is why I offered the second solution as well.  I'm glad it worked out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both options. As implied by my nickname, I'm a rookie in the Python/Pandas world.

Comment: @The_rookie there is no shame in being a rookie.  One only has to look at my first questions to know I was right there with you at one time.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I promise you I'm not getting defensive.  Tone is lost in comments and chat and other such medium.  When I comment to people I don't know, I try to be as matter of fact as I can.  Among those I'm more familiar, I may attempt humor.  But if you read my comment again, take out the tone and all that's left is me being honest about my choices.  I suspect I'll see you answering quite a few questions.  I'd rather we understand each other and together we all can be more helpful to the community... Til the next question (-:

Comment: np, all good :) btw I found a comprehensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way which takes advantage of `numpy` array performance:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[[111240.0, 110530.0, 108540.0, 108540.0]],
                   [[117240.0, 119160.0, 120160.0, 121950.0]],
                   [[180420.0, 180420.0, 183840.0, 183840.0]],
                   [[160260.0, 159430.0, 159430.0, 157720.0]]], columns=['Counts'])

df['mean'] = np.mean(np.vstack(df['Counts'].values), axis=1)

#                                      Counts      mean
# 0  [111240.0, 110530.0, 108540.0, 108540.0]  109712.5
# 1  [117240.0, 119160.0, 120160.0, 121950.0]  119627.5
# 2  [180420.0, 180420.0, 183840.0, 183840.0]  182130.0
# 3  [160260.0, 159430.0, 159430.0, 157720.0]  159210.0
```

Comment: The following error message was displayed :
    ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
I guess it is because each row has different lengths. I wanted to share this with you. The problem was solved using the previous post.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: The error is due to the fact that not all list/arrays in `Counts` are the same length.  Therefore, Numpy can't make it a rectangular ndarray.  It, instead, turns it into a one dimensional array of lists which borks on `axis=1`.  That said, the call to `np.vstack` is additional overhead that isn't needed.  For small data, this is more performant `np.mean(df['Counts'].values.tolist(), axis=1)`.  It's good to get the performance perspective as well.  +1 from me.