# how to sort with condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

How do I construct a sort with conditions in python? Let's say if I have a list

```
a: [-1, 3, 4, 2, -1, -1, 1, 0]
```

How do I sort only the elements that is not -1? (In return:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -1, 3, 4] )
```

How do I sort every other element?
(In return a: `[-1, 3, -1, 2, 1, -1, 4, 0]`
)
The syntax of the code is wrong, but would it be something similar to this?

```
result=sorted(a, key=lambda x: x!=-1,reverse=True)
result=sorted(a, key=lambda x: [::2],reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a vectorised approach interests you, this is possible via 3rd party library `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([-1, 3, 4, 2, -1, -1, 1, 0])

a[a!=-1] = np.sort(a[a!=-1])

# array([-1,  0,  1,  2, -1, -1,  3,  4])
```

---

Sorting every other element is equally trivial:

```
a[::2] = np.sort(a[::2])

# array([-1,  3, -1,  2,  1, -1,  4,  0])
```

---

Related: [Why NumPy instead of Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `next` and `iter` after sorting all contents from `s` that are positive:

```
def sort_by(s, avoid = -1):
  sorted_vals = iter(sorted(filter(lambda x:x >= 0, s)))
  return [i if i == avoid else next(sorted_vals) for i in s]

print(sort_by([-1, 3, 4, 2, -1, -1, 1, 0]))
```

Output:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for showing this! Although the answer for this list is correct, But if I want to sort only the numbers that's not -1....so if I have -2 in my list, this will not work.

Comment: @JingLi I updated the solution to include a function that can receive two parameters: the list to be sorted, and the value to avoid.