# python - processing parent list containing child lists (with variable count)

Tags: python

As an input, I get a master list containing child lists (with variable count).

```
masterList = [[23,12],[34,21],[25,20]]
```

Number of child lists varies. 3 child lists are shown here, but the number can vary.
I wish to get max of first records and min of second records.
In this case, I know I can hard code like this...

```
maxNum = max(masterList[0][0], masterList[1][0], masterList[2][0])
```

How do I write a module for accepting masterList with varying number of child lists and getting max, min?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the child list contains always 2 elements?

Comment: yes. the number of records in child list are fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
masterList = [[23,12],[34,21],[25,20]]
first, second = zip(*masterList)
print(max(first))
print(min(second))
```

Edit: for data with sublists containing more than two elements, you can use Python3 unpacking to account for the rest:

```
masterList = [[23,12, 24],[34,21, 23],[25,20, 23, 23]]
first, second, *_ = zip(*masterList)
print(max(first))
print(min(second))
```

Output:

```
34
12
```

Comment: which might be faster? this or the one suggested by @Gabriel?

Comment: This wouldn't work in his case, if it is of varying length , you will not get the result in some cases as zip will omit subsequent values

Comment: as long as each sub list has exactly 2 elements it works.

Comment: @Vineet, I doubt speed is a concern. *But* if it is, use a vectorised approach.

Comment: whether zip holds resulting list in-memory? because I have input with huge size, >15000 records. Will it cause overhead?

Comment: @Vineet With `zip`, memory should not be an issue in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator in order to extract the relevant element of each inner list.

```
max(innerList[0] for innerList in masterList)

min(innerList[1] for innerList in masterList)
```

Comment: I had thought about this. But wouldn't it create 2 more lists? My data is huge in size. What is your opinion?

Comment: @Vineet Nope. It creates a generator (not a new `list` object) that iterates over the original list. No wasted memory.

Comment: @Vineet It only creates a new `list` object if you put the comprehension between `[` and `]`, e.g. `max([innerList[0] for innerList in masterList])`

Comment: @Vineet I've edited my answer to correct the term (it's a _generator_, not _list comprehension_). Also you can read the answers of the following question to better understand the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension/47793

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are looking for a way to get the max of all 0th index and the min of all the 1st index elements.

```
max_of_first_element = max(masterList, key = lambda x:x[0])[0]
min_of_second_element = min(masterList, key = lambda x:x[1])[1]
```

if you need the min not for the second element but for the last element always, then :

```
min_of_last_element = min(masterList, key = lambda x:x[-1])[-1]
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I want the min for 2nd element; may not be the last. Then what the code should be?

Comment: use the first code that I have entered. for the min_of_second_element.

Answer (score 1):

To get the max/min of all first/second elements of your child lists, you can do this:

```
maxNum = max(childlist[0] for childList in masterList)
minNum = min(childlist[1] for childList in masterList)
```

Comment: I had thought about this. But wouldn't it create 2 more lists? My data is huge in size. What is your opinion?

Comment: Yes you are right, this would create 2 new lists which is actually not necessary. It is better to omit the square brackets, then generators are used. I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, use `numpy`.

This is efficient for larger arrays versus list-based methods.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[23,12],[34,21],[25,20]])

res = A[:, 0].max(), A[:, 1].min()

# (34, 12)
```

This solution handles any length of lists / sublists in a vectorised fashion. The only requirement is that each sublist is the same length.

Related: [Why NumPy instead of Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists)

Comment: thanks @jpp. But when the need can be satisfied very well using built in generator, why to go for 3rd party lib

Comment: @Vineet, see update. One analogy is using a grill to toast your bread instead of a purpose-built toaster. Yes, it works, but it's inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try :

```
import operator
max(masterList, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
#34
min(masterList, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]
#12
```

Comment: From the question they need `get max of first records` so it should be `max...itemgetter(0)`  right?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM `operator.itemgetter(1)` will give you a function that grabs the `first item` from a list-like object.

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(1)` will return the second item from the list as the index starts from zero.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM The way `operator.itemgetter(n)` works is it constructs a callable that assumes an iterable object (e.g. list, tuple, set) as input, and fetches the n-th element out of it. So here calling it with argument 1 or 0 will not matter. It will return a tuple containing the maximum of both the columns. Hence note the subscript at the end `[0]` which means to say show max for only first column (and `[1]` in min means to say show min for only second column). So here `operator.itemgetter(0)` and `operator.itemgetter(1)` will work the same

Answer (score 1):

you can just use built-in function sort, it doesn't use loops so its an efficient method.

```
largest = sorted(masterList, reverse=True)[0][0]
smallest = sorted(masterList, key=lambda masterList: masterList[1])[0][1]
```