# python: Splitting a list into n sublists by index

Tags: python, list, split, sublist

I hope this question isn't a duplicate; I found similar ones but not exactly what I need.

I want an efficient way to split a list into *n* sublists where each index goes to a different list until we reach the *nth* index and then the next *n* indexes go to the lists we already have, in the same order, and so on...

For example, given the following list:

```
l = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
n = 3
```

In this case I need to split the list into 3 lists with this desired output:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

I can make *n* for loops that will skip every *nth* step, but I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: if `n=4 or 2` what is the expected output

Comment: problem statement no so clear

Comment: Can you explain expected output for the same list if `n` is `4`?

Comment: OK, let say  l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], n = 4 =>  output:[[1,5], [2,6], [3,7],[4,8]]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `zip` and list comprehension

```
l = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
n = 3
print([list(i) for i in zip(*[l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)])])
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

**Note:** You can also use `from itertools import izip_longest` if the chunks are uneven.

Comment: You can write it as `map(list, zip(*[l[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(l),n)]))`

Comment: @bro-grammer. Thanks, but in python3 you need to again use list. `print(list(map(list, zip(*[l[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(l),n)]))))`

Comment: it's working, but can you explain what the * is for?

Answer (score 1):

For the loop method you describe, see [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

A [better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists) would be to use a 3rd party library such as `numpy`. This takes advantage of vectorised computations:

**Example #1**

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
n = 3

res = l.reshape((len(l)/n), n).T

print(res)

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

---

**Example #2**

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
n = 4

res = l.reshape((len(l)/n, n)).T

print(res)

array([[1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 8]])
```

Comment: i saw the question  "How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?"  and all other similar questions but it's not the same kind of chunks. you should know since your answer has the right outcome

Comment: @OrtalTurgeman, Well, the logic still works (still update). Up to you, though, if you like lists of lists.

Comment: you're answer seems to be good and clean but 'numpy' requires installation, it's not a base python package (i'm using python 2.7), so i preferred the first answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found another answer, very simple, using modulo:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
n = 4
for i in range (n):
    a.append([])
for i in range(len(l)):
    a[i%n].append(l[i])
```

output:

```
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```