# How to create a binary matrix with some given condition below:

Tags: python, list, for-loop, matrix, tuples

For a given list of tuples L whose elements are taken from range(n), I want to create A binary matrix A of order n in the following way:

```
If (i,j)  or (j,i) in L then A[i][j]=1 otherwise A[i][j]=0.
```

Let us consider the following example:

```
L=[(2,3),(0,1),(1,3),(2,0),(0,3)]
A=[[0]*4]*4
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if (i,j) or (j,i) in L:
            A[i][j]=1
        else:
            A[i][j]=0

print A
```

This program does not give the accurate result. Where is the logical mistake occurred?

Comment: What do you mean under "does not give the accurate result"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Change `A=[[0]*4]*4` to `A=[[0]*4 for _ in range(4)]` and `(i,j) or (j,i) in L` to `(i,j) in L or (j,i) in L`.

Comment: I mean the out put should A=[[0,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,1,1,0]] @zwer

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thank you for your correction. Now this gives the desired result.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Can you explain please. When I use A=[[0]*4]*4, the outcome gives wrong but when I use A=[[0]*4 for _ in range(4)], the outcome is correct, Why?

Comment: It's already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a 3rd party library, `numpy`, for matrix calculations.

Python lists of lists are inefficient for numeric arrays.

```
import numpy as np

L = [(2,3),(0,1),(1,3),(2,0),(0,3)]

A = np.zeros((4, 4))

idx = np.r_[L].T
A[idx[0], idx[1]] = 1
```

Result:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Related: [Why NumPy instead of Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists)

Answer (score 0):

According to Aran-Fey's correction the answer is :

```
L=[(2,3),(0,1),(1,3),(2,0),(0,3)]
#A=[[0]*4]*4
A=[[0]*4 for _ in range(4)]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if (i,j) in L or (j,i) in L:
            A[i][j]=1
        else:
            A[i][j]=0

print A
```