# Merge list into sparse list efficiently

Tags: python, list, performance

I have two lists:

```
a = [None, None, 1, None, 4, None, None, 5, None]
b = [7,8,2,3,6,9]
```

I want to merge them, either to create a new list or just update a, by filling in the Nones with the values from b, so

```
a = [7,8,1,2,4,3,6,5,9]
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

For extension, I'll be wanting to do this with every permutation of b. Does this allow shortcutting the technique at all?

Comment: Can `b` contain less or more elements than necessary?

Comment: No - we can assume b is the right size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one approach. Using a list comprehension and converting `b` to a iterator object.

**Demo:**

```
a = [None, None, 1, None, 4, None, None, 5, None]
b = [7,8,2,3,6,9]
b = iter(b)

print( [next(b) if i is None else i for i in a] )
```

**Output:**

```
[7, 8, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for reversed_index in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
    if a[reversed_index] is None:
        a[reversed_index] = b.pop()
```

It should be efficient as it modifies `a` in place and right popping a list is also efficient. As far as I think, it is an `O(len(a))` solution.

Answer (score 3):

With `list.pop()` method on reversed 2nd `b` list:

```
a = [None, None, 1, None, 4, None, None, 5, None]
b = [7,8,2,3,6,9]
tmp = b[::-1]

result = [tmp.pop() if i is None else i for i in a]
print(result)    # [7, 8, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Great solution.  In my testing the iterator one is faster still, but it's close.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive apporach:

```
a = [None, None, 1, None, 4, None, None, 5, None]
b = [7,8,2,3,6,9]

def recursion_approach(first_list,second_list):

    for index,value in enumerate(first_list):
            if value!=None:
                first_list[index]=value
            else:
                first_list[index]=second_list[0]
                recursion_approach(first_list,second_list[1:])

    return first_list

print(recursion_approach(a,b))
```

output:

```
[7, 8, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution - as you might expect, it's not very fast though.

Answer (score 1):

For performance with large lists, you may find 3rd party libraries more efficient, for example via Pandas or NumPy.

#### pandas

Create 2 series and use assignment with Boolean indexing:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([None, None, 1, None, 4, None, None, 5, None])
b = pd.Series([7,8,2,3,6,9])

a[a.isnull()] = b.values

print(a.values.astype(int).tolist())

# [7, 8, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 9]
```

#### numpy

Similarly with NumPy provided you use `np.nan` instead of `None`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan])
b = np.array([7,8,2,3,6,9])

a[np.isnan(a)] = b

# array([ 7.,  8.,  1.,  2.,  4.,  3.,  6.,  5.,  9.])
```

See also [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists).