# List with 100 elements each element 30 long

Tags: python

I would like to create a list that is 100 elements long but each element is 30 long. The elements with a length of 30 would be made up of random numbers from [0,1] excluding 1.

I'm thinking I need a for loop or some sort of append.

My expected outcome would be something like:

[Random numbers between 0-1 excluding 1, Random numbers between 0-1 excluding 1, Same here,..., and the same idea here. ]

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code you've come up with so far?

Comment: I'm not sure what your expected output is. You want a nested list? A list of length 100 containing lists of length 30 containing numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using ***numpy***, then you can avoid nested loops and append statements. Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
random_matrix = np.random.rand(100,30)
```

Comment: This would create a list with 30 elements of length 30 right?

Comment: @ pckofwolfs I have edited my comment. This, would create a numpy array with 100 elements, each of length 30, which is pretty much the same as python list, but implemented in a more compact way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists

Comment: so to use this in my purpose I would want to have 30,100 then?

Comment: @pckofwolfs no, it should be as written in my comment. It will create an array of 100 elements, where each element has the size of 30. (30, 100) will create an array of 30 elements, each with the size of 100

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time and responses. I forgot I can size my list's in different ways.

Comment: @pckofwolfs My pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `list comprehension` and `random.uniform` function:

```
 import random
 expected_list = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(30)] for j in range(100)]
 print(expected_list)
```

Comment: Doesn't `random.random()` already returns values in the interval [0,1.0) ? Is there any difference when using `random.random` and `random.uniform(0,1)` when working with the [0,1) interval ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
list = [[random.uniform(0, 0.9999999999999999) for y in range(30)] for x in range(100)]
print(list)
```