# Python: Speed up matching in multiple lists

Tags: python, performance, list, tuples, matching

I have four lists like these:

```
L = [ (1,2), (3,5), (6,10), (7,8) ]
M = [ (1,3), (8,9), (12,13) ]
N = [ (6,10), (3,4), (5,6), (10,11), (12,13) ]
T = [ (6,10) , (1,4) ]
```

I want to check the presence/absence of every tuple of T inside L, M, and N:

```
[[True, False, True], [False, False, False]]
```

The following works but it is incredibly inefficient when the size of T, L, M, and N grows.

```
[[ y in x for x in [L, M, N] ] for y in T ]
```

What is the most efficient way to speed up this for large lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching in `list` time is proportional to the list length. So it's high for long lists. There are special data structures optimized for searching. The easiest in python is `set`. It calculates the hash of each element (so the elements must be hashable, and tuples of integers are OK).
Then you do the same check. So you just need to add

```
L = set(L)
M = set(M)
N = set(N)
```

As a side effect you will lose the order of elements in the list. And if there are non unique values they will be merged into one.

Moreover sets have method for finding common elements. `L & M` will give you elements which exists in `L` and in `M`. That would be the fastest solution.

**About speed of search an item in list and set:**
Speed of search in `list` might be high if the searched values are at the very beginning (or the list is short). But if it is not the case `set` is much-much faster as time of search is proportional to log(len(data)). The worst case for `list` is when there are no searched items in the `list`, so it will need to check every item. In this case searching in 1M `list` would be 200K slower, than in `set` (just checked in python3)

Comment: ...and that'll give a 30% speedup without major algorithm changes.

Comment: @ForceBru For large involved sets/lists, this should be a much more significant improvement. Where do you get that number from?

Comment: @schwobaseggl, I also think so. `set`s are awesome! I just tested this on my machine.

Comment: I've just tested for list of 1M values, and set was about 100 times faster than list

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into using Numpy arrays instead of normal python lists and tuples.
look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists)
Since you have to check every element in your list the total speed will always scale linear so you have to use a faster implementation like the numpy one or extend your code with a faster language like Rust, C, C++.

Use the `np.asarray(listname)` function to convert it

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle a different output format, you can also you set intersection.

```
>>> L = set([ (1,2), (3,5), (6,10), (7,8) ])
>>> M = set([ (1,3), (8,9), (12,13) ])
>>> N = set([ (6,10), (3,4), (5,6), (10,11), (12,13) ])
>>> T = set([ (6,10) , (1,4) ])
>>> [T & x for x in (L,M,N)]
[{(6, 10)}, set(), {(6, 10)}]
```

This will give you a list of sets of tuples which appear in both sets each. This should be faster than using nested loops.

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary and compare those values instead.

```
LMNT = {'L':[(1,2),(3,5),(6,10),(7,8)],
'M':[(1,3),(8,9),(12,13)],
'N':[ (6,10), (3,4), (5,6), (10,11), (12,13) ],
'T':[ (6,10) , (1,4) ]}
```

Then you can compare the dictionary.
`LMNT['M'][0][1]` values is 2

OR

`LMNT['N'][4]` values is `(12,13)`

Comment: This will be less efficient than OP's original code. Now it takes longer because the lists are still lists, but with the extra cost of a dictionary lookup.