# Record included for each document - processing CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large CSV file with the following structure:

```
doc_id, inclusion, id
 1, TRUE, 842
 1, FALSE, 768
 1, FALSE, 292
 1, FALSE, 393
 2, TRUE, 191
 2, TRUE, 389
 2, TRUE, 171
 ...
```

The `id` is the primary key. `doc_id` is a foreign and represents the document which each id is linked to. Many id's are linked to each document. Each `id` is classified as included (ie. `inclusion == True`) or excluded (ie. `inclusion == False`).

I need to create a summary table which displays for each `doc_id`, the number of `id`'s included and excluded. I can do this for all `doc_id`'s but am not sure how to implement it for each `doc_id`. For example, for the data above I want:

```
doc_id included excluded
1      1        3
2      3        0
...
```

This is my current code:

```
for index, row in citationData.iterrows():
    if row.included == True:
        inc = inc + 1
    else:
        exc = exc + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html).

```
res = pd.crosstab(df['doc_id'], df['inclusion'])

print(res)

inclusion  False  True 
doc_id                 
1              3      1
2              0      3
```

In general, you should avoid Python-level loops when working with Pandas / NumPy arrays.

Comment: Many thanks. Why should I avoid loops with Panda/NumPy arrays?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25778164/9209546) has a nice description (with comparison to lists). Essentially, you are doing more work at C-level than Python-level.

Answer (score 0):

You can `agg` with `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

s = df.groupby('doc_id').inclusion.agg(Counter)

doc_id
1    {' TRUE': 1, ' FALSE': 3}
2                 {' TRUE': 3}
Name: inclusion, dtype: object
```

If you need a `dataframe`, just use the default constructor.

```
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index).fillna(0)

         FALSE  TRUE
doc_id      
1        3      1
2        0      3
```