# Efficient way to generate total scores along with numpy.unique()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My task is as follows:

Each rows of the `labels` represents students id who received awards from a certain competition. Each competitions have different weighting factors which are given by the `weights`.

`scores`of students are calculated as weighted number of awards that they received. What I have so far is:

```
import numpy as np

labels = np.array([
    [0,1,5],
    [0,1,3],
    [2,4,5]])
weights = np.array([
    [1],
    [2],
    [4]])

c_labels = np.concatenate(labels)
c_weights = np.concatenate(np.broadcast_to(weights,(3,3)))
uni, inv = np.unique(c_labels,return_inverse=True)

scores = np.zeros(len(uni))
for i in uni:
    scores[i] = np.sum(c_weights[inv==i])
print(scores)
```

In the above, I have simplified my task as the student scoring problem to explain clearly. This is part of my bigger task, and I need to generate the unique array of the `labels` and the corresponding `scores` array to proceed.

The actual data size is huge and I need to reiterate this many times, so I can't use for loops as it takes too long time. I wish I can change to a more efficient way (i.e. replace the last for-loop into an array operation somehow), but I don't know how. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.bincount`

```
scores = np.bincount(inv, weights = c_weights)
```

Answer (score 1):

does this help?

```
id_scores = np.zeros(labels.max()+1)

for i in range(len(labels)):
    id_scores[labels[i]]+=weights[i]
    
print(id_scores)
```

if this is still too slow, you'll have to resort to writing this function in Cython or coming up with some messy "native" numpy solution. Also are there any gaps between the IDs? If yes then it might make more sense to have an ID to index lookup table as well. For example (let's say the IDs are in the format of `studentXYZ`):

```
student0 -> 0
student4 -> 1
student9 -> 2
...
```

Edit: I'm aware that Python loops are "slow" but if you actually benchmark the code, the accepted solution is far slower than my solution:

```
import numpy as np

n_students = 10_000
max_weight = 10
students_per_row = 1000
rows = 1000


labels = np.random.randint(0,n_students,(rows,students_per_row))
weights = np.random.randint(0,max_weight,(rows,1))

def accepted_solution(labels, weights):
    c_labels = np.concatenate(labels)
    c_weights = np.concatenate(np.broadcast_to(weights,labels.shape))
    uni, inv = np.unique(c_labels,return_inverse=True)
    
    return np.bincount(inv, weights = c_weights)

def my_solution(labels, weights):
    id_scores = np.zeros(labels.max()+1)
    flat_view = weights.ravel()
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        id_scores[labels[i]]+=flat_view[i]
        
    return id_scores
```

[image]

My code also comes with the benefit that it produces correct results, even if some student IDs aren't present in the `labels` array. For example, if we have 10K students but `labels` is 100x100, then some students could be missing scores. the accepted solution just drops the zeros, so you wouldn't be able to tell for which student IDs the scores are calculated.

Nothing will ever be faster than doing the minimum amount of work, regardless of how "inefficient" a Python loop is.

Comment: This is still too slow. But thanks for your answer

Comment: @KayK. how are you measuring the performance? based on the small input you gave, my solution runs twice as fast as the answer you accepted (your solution:98us, accepted answer: 47us, my solution 22us).

Comment: @OM222O: [relevant context for `numpy` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603487/speed-comparison-numpy-vs-python-standard/52605202#52605202)

Comment: @DanielF don't you worry, I'm testing a much larger dataset

Comment: The data size is about 100M (the label is 10K x 10K). And I repeat the whole procedure for about 1K times. I am skeptical that the for-loop can still be faster.

Comment: @KayK. I'm running with 10Kx10K as we speak, instead of doing "eyeball statistics" and "guesstimating", do yourself a favor and actually run the numbers next time.

Comment: @KayK. `bincount` solution: `38.8 s ± 1.97 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` , my solution: `5.65 s ± 678 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. Feel free to run the numbers for yourself.

Comment: I accepted the other solution because that was the kind of solution I was looking for (for-loop-less). But I will rigorously compare both solutions and report. Thanks

Comment: @KayK. you do realize that numpy isn't magic and it's still not "for-loop-less", right? the only difference is the for loops are in C++ instead of Python. On my machine, an empty loop in Python can easily do 36 million iterations per second so that will never be a bottleneck. The actual code inside the loop matters and my code does much less work (fancy indexing and addition) whereas the other code does A LOT more work.

Comment: Here's an update. I applied both solutions to my actual program. And the @DanielF 's solution is much faster. I realized that it's because of the sparsity, i.e. only small portion of students receive awards. In this case, you'll understand why I get that outcome. I do see that when good portion of the total population receive awards, then your solution is faster. So it all depends on the distribution I would say.

Comment: @KayK. Ofcourse it does! go back to my earlier comments about gaps in student IDs and mention of a lookup table. If you're happy with that solution then sure, but algorithmically speaking the accepted solution is insanely inefficient and if you add a LUT to my solution it'll continue to be faster even for the sparse case. I won't bother updating the code though

Comment: The student id & scoring model was just to explain the problem to ask here. In my actual task, the labels are a series of coordinates, and those coordinates change on every iteration. So I can't use a fixed LUT. So I am still happy with the accepted solution. But I do really appreciate your effort to try to make me understand. Honestly, at the very beginning I misunderstood your solution, and then I understood what your solution was doing. I learned from you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following will help:

1. Instead of `np.concatenate`, you can `.flatten()` the `c_labels`.
2. Thereafter, you can `np.repeat(weights.flatten(), labels.shape[1])`, which will do the same as `np.concatenate(np.broadcast_to..))`.
3. Keep `uni, inv = np.unique(c_labels, return_inverse=True)` the same.
4. Make a score array filled with zeros (i.e. `np.zeros`) with the size of `uni`.
5. Use `np.add.at(scores, inv, c_weights)` to obtain the results you want.

The `np.add.at` should do the job. Just to give you an idea of how it works:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
np.add.at(a, [2, 2, 2], 5)
```

will result in:

```
[0 0 15 0 0]
```

i.e. 5 is added 3 times to index 2.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think np.add.at(scores, inv, c_weights) would work.