# Grouping all column values of a pandas dataframe into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['A','B','C','A'], 'b':[1,4,1,3], 'c':[0,6,1,0], 'd':[1,0,0,5]})
```

I want a dataframe that will look like this:

[image]

The original dataframe was grouped by values in column 'a' and its corresponding values are saved as a dictionary in a new column 'dict'. The key - value pairs are the column name and values in the column respectively. In case if a value in column 'a' has multiple entries (for eg A in column 'a' occurs twice), then a list of dictionary should be created for the same value.

How can I do this ?(Please ignore the grammatical mistakes and please ask any doubts regarding the question if it sounded too vague)

Comment: **Why** precisely do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Don't do this**. Pandas was never designed to hold list/tuples/dicts in series / columns. You can concoct expensive workarounds, but these are not
>   recommended.
>
> The main reason holding lists in series is not recommended is you lose
>   the vectorised functionality which goes with using NumPy arrays held in contiguous memory blocks. Your series will be of
>   `object` dtype, which represents a sequence of pointers, much like `list`. You will lose
>   benefits in terms of memory and performance, as well as access to optimized Pandas methods.
>
> See also [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python
>   lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)
>   The arguments in favour of Pandas are the same as for NumPy.

But if really need it:

```
df = df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='dict')
print (df)
   a                                               dict
0  A  [{'a': 'A', 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}, {'a': 'A'...
1  B               [{'a': 'B', 'b': 4, 'c': 6, 'd': 0}]
2  C               [{'a': 'C', 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0}]
```

Comment: I suspect the "if really need it" is a class XY problem ;)

Comment: @jezrael thanks ! this worked.Since you said pandas are not designed to hold list/tuples/dicts in columns, can you tell me how this can be done in numpy array?

Comment: @RemyM - pandas is designed for working with scalars, numpy too.