# Accessing a tuple in enumerate?

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I want to iterate through a list and sum all the elements. Except, if the number is a 5, I want to skip the number following that 5. So for example:

`x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3]   #should results in 30`.

I'm just not sure how I can access the index of a tuple, when I use enumerate. What I want to do, is use an if statement, that if the number at the previous index == 5, continue the loop.

Thanks you

Comment: `enumerate` gives you the index and the value. `for i, value in enumerate(x)` where `i` is the index

Comment: What do you mean you can’t access the index of a triple using enumerate? enumerate returns a generator of (index, value) pairs. Just iterate over that object returned by enumerate using something like `for index, value in enumerate(obj)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a fan of bug-ridden one-liners that get upvoted.

So here's the answer with a for-loop.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3, 5] #should results in 35. 

s = 0
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    if i != 0 and x[i-1] == 5: 
        continue 
    s += v

print(s)
```

Comment: I would prefer if you commented on each buggy oneliner individually instead of dismissing all of them. But your solution is straight forward and deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

The [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has a recipe for this called **`pairwise`**. You can either copy-paste the function or import it from [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) (which needs to be installed).

Demo:

```
>>> from more_itertools import pairwise
>>> 
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3]
>>> x[0] + sum(m for n, m in pairwise(x) if n != 5)
30
```

edit:

> **But what if my datastructure is iterable, but does not support indexing?**

In this case, the above solution needs a minor modification.

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> from more_itertools import pairwise
>>> 
>>> x = (n for n in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3]) # generator, no indices!
>>> it1, it2 = tee(x)
>>> next(it1, 0) + sum(m for n, m in pairwise(it2) if n != 5)
30
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sum` with `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3]
print(sum(v for i, v in enumerate(x) if (i == 0) or (x[i-1] != 5)))
```

**Output:**

```
30
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, verbose way:

```
SKIP_PREV = 5
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3]
prev = -1
s = 0
for num in x:
    if prev != SKIP_PREV:
        s += num
    prev = num
print(s)
# 30
```

Compact, maybe less clear way:

```
SKIP_PREV = 5
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3]
s = sum(num for i, num in enumerate(x) if i == 0 or x[i - 1] != SKIP_PREV)
print(s)
# 30
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use NumPy with integer indexing:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3])

res = x.sum() - x[np.where(x == 5)[0]+1].sum()  # 30
```

See also [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can pair the list with a shifted version of itself.  This should work:

```
sum(val for (prev, val)
    in zip(itertools.chain((None,), x), x)
    if prev != 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The longest code so far. Anyway, it does not need enumerate, it is a simple [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3]
skip = False
s = 0 
for v in x:
    if skip:
        skip = False
    else:
        s += v
        skip = v == 5
print(s)
```