# Splitting a string into list and converting the items to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe where I have a column `values` like this:

```
0       16 0
1    7 1 2 0
2          5
3          1
4         18
```

What I want is to create another column, `modified_values`, that contains a list of all the different numbers that I will get after splitting each value. The new column will be like this:

```
0       [16, 0]
1    [7, 1, 2, 0]
2          [5]
3          [1]
4         [18]
```

**Beware** the values in this list should be `int` and not `strings`.

Things that I am aware of:

1) I can split the column in a vectorized way like this
`df.values.str.split(" ")`. This will give me the list but the objects inside the list will be strings. I can add another operation on top of that like this `df.values.str.split(" ").apply(func to convert values to int)` but that wouldn't be vectorized

2) I can directly do this `df['modified_values']= df['values'].apply(func that splits as well as converts to int)`

The second one will be much slower than the first for sure but I am wondering if the same thing can be achieved in a vectorized way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### No native "vectorised" solution is possible

I'm highlighting this because it's a common mistake to assume [`pd.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) methods are vectorised. They aren't. They offer convenience and error-handling at the cost of efficiency. For **clean data only**, e.g. no `NaN` values, a list comprehension is likely your best option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['16 0', '7 1 2 0', '5', '1', '18']})

df['B'] = [list(map(int, i.split())) for i in df['A']]

print(df)

         A             B
0     16 0       [16, 0]
1  7 1 2 0  [7, 1, 2, 0]
2        5           [5]
3        1           [1]
4       18          [18]
```

#### Performance benchmarking

To illustrate performance issues with `pd.Series.str`, you can see for larger dataframes how the more operations you pass to Pandas, the more performance deteriorates:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit [list(map(int, i.split())) for i in df['A']]            # 55.6 ms
%timeit [list(map(int, i)) for i in df['A'].str.split()]        # 80.2 ms
%timeit df['A'].str.split().apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))  # 93.6 ms
```

#### `list` as elements in `pd.Series` is also anti-Pandas

As [described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373714/generic-dont-do-it-answer), holding lists in series gives 2 layers of pointers and is not recommended:

> **Don't do this**. Pandas was never designed to hold lists in series / columns. You can concoct expensive workarounds, but these are not
>   recommended.
>
> The main reason holding lists in series is not recommended is you lose
>   the vectorised functionality which goes with using NumPy arrays held in contiguous memory blocks. Your series will be of
>   `object` dtype, which represents a sequence of pointers, much like `list`. You will lose
>   benefits in terms of memory and performance, as well as access to optimized Pandas methods.
>
> See also [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python
>   lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)
>   The arguments in favour of Pandas are the same as for NumPy.

Comment: Good to dispell the misconception that `.str` methods are good here, but maybe it's worth mentioning that the resultant structure also doesn't really fit the pandas criteria?

Comment: @roganjosh, Yep, good point. This calls for a copy-paste edit :)

Comment: @jpp thanks for the detailed answer and much needed clarification regarding `str`

Comment: The double `for` comprehension is faster than the `map` one. And Numba is 250 times faster, but with NaNs. See my answer.

Comment: @keiv.fly, Good spot re: nested list comp! Of course the `numba` result is technically different (but actually better given no `list`).

Answer (score 2):

The double `for` comprehension is 33% faster than the `map` comprehension from the jpp's answer. Numba trick is 250 times faster than the `map` comprehension from jpp's answer, but you get a pandas DataFrame with floats and `nan`'s and not a series of lists. Numba is included in Anaconda.

Benchmarks:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(nb_calc(df.A))            # numba trick       0.144 ms
%timeit [int(x) for i in df['A'] for x in i.split()]            # 23.6   ms
%timeit [list(map(int, i.split())) for i in df['A']]            # 35.6   ms
%timeit [list(map(int, i)) for i in df['A'].str.split()]        # 50.9   ms
%timeit df['A'].str.split().apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))  # 56.6   ms
```

Code for Numba function:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def str2int_nb(nb_a):
    n1 = nb_a.shape[0]
    n2 = nb_a.shape[1]
    res = np.empty(nb_a.shape)
    res[:] = np.nan
    j_res_max = 0
    for i in range(n1):
        j_res = 0
        s = 0
        for j in range(n2):
            x = nb_a[i,j]
            if x == 32:
                res[i,j_res]=np.float64(s)
                s=0
                j_res+=1
            elif x == 0:
                break
            else:
                s=s*10+x-48
        res[i,j_res]=np.float64(s)
        if j_res>j_res_max:
            j_res_max = j_res

    return res[:,:j_res_max+1]

def nb_calc(s):
    a_temp = s_a.values.astype("U")
    nb_a = a_temp.view("uint32").reshape(len(s_a),-1).astype(np.int8)
    str2int_nb(nb_a)
```

Numba does not support strings. So I first convert to array of int8 and only then work with it. Conversion to int8 actually takes 3/4 of the execution time.

The output of my numba function looks like this:

```
      0    1    2    3
-----------------------
0  16.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1   7.0  1.0  2.0  0.0
2   5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  18.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```