# Set Pandas column values to an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following problem:
I have a dataframe like this one:

```
   col1   col2   col3
0   2       5      4
1   4       3      5
2   6       2      7
```

Now I have an array for example a = [5,5,5] and i want to insert this array in col3 but only in specific rows (let's say 0 and 2) and obtain something like that:

```
   col1   col2   col3
0   2       5    [5,5,5]
1   4       3      5
2   6       2    [5,5,5]
```

The problem is that when I try to do:

```
 zip_df.at[[0,2],'col3'] = a
```

I receive the following error `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're attempting is not recommended.<sup>1</sup> Pandas is not designed to hold list in series. Having said this, you can define a series explicitly and assign via [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) or [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Note [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) is used to get or set a *single value* only, not multiple values as in your case.

```
a = [5, 5, 5]
indices = [0, 2]

df['col3'].update(pd.Series([a]*len(indices), index=indices))

# alternative:
# df.loc[indices, 'col3'] = pd.Series([a]*len(indices), index=indices)

print(df)

   col1  col2       col3
0     2     5  [5, 5, 5]
1     4     3          5
2     6     2  [5, 5, 5]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For more information ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373714/generic-dont-do-it-answer)):

> **Don't do this**. Pandas was never designed to hold lists in series / columns. You can concoct expensive workarounds, but these are not
>   recommended.
>
> The main reason holding lists in series is not recommended is you lose
>   the vectorised functionality which goes with using NumPy arrays held in contiguous memory blocks. Your series will be of
>   `object` dtype, which represents a sequence of pointers, much like `list`. You will lose
>   benefits in terms of memory and performance, as well as access to optimized Pandas methods.
>
> See also [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python
>   lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)
>   The arguments in favour of Pandas are the same as for NumPy.