# What is if(e & 1) means in python?

Tags: bitwise-and

So I was reading a question on SO and I don't understand the code of the answer it has. It is doing some bit wise operation but i don't know how that works and what is actually going on within the while loop and the need of mod at `b2 = (b2*b2) % m`

```
        b2 = b                         
        res = 1                        
         while e:                       
            if e & 1:                  
                res = (res * b2) % m   
            b2 = (b2*b2) % m        
            e >>= 1
```

Can anyone help me to understand it ?

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440590/why-operation-on-list-is-slower-than-operation-on-numpy-array)

Comment: You have any guess on your own what it could do?

Comment: I think it is bit wise operation but i am not sure and i don't know how that works

Comment: How about you open an interactive Python sessionl, test some value and see the result?

Comment: I did but I want to know what is actually going on within the `while e`  loop

Comment: There is no `while` in your question. And no, the linked one does not count.

Comment: I have edited the question maybe that will clear my point of doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bitwise AND operation. In bitwise binary operations, the two numbers in their binary form are processed by their corresponding bits. So 1 is only one bit. It will be compared to last bit of a number. So a&1 will return 1 if last bit of 1 is 1 and zero otherwise. So the if block will be executed accordingly
eg
12 AND 1
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
_________
0 0 0 0

Comment: What do you mean by **two numbers in their binary form are processed by their corresponding bits** ? Any why its making its mod of m  twice ?

Comment: I mean just write the numbers in their binary form,one below the other(same way we write to add two numbers) such that their last bit matches. So then perform AND on each pair of bits. So for 1101 AND 1 you will write 1101 AND 0001 . It gives 0001. this way