# Why numpy array takes more time than list?

Tags: python, numpy

Why is numpy slower in this code?

```
for i in range(10000):
    array = [[0.0,] * 1024 for x in range(1024)]
```

0,021539204 seconds time elapsed (39.616.810 instructions)

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(10000):
    array = np.zeros((1024,1024))
```

0.209111860 seconds time elapsed (1.067.923.180 instructions)

Comment: `array = [[0.0,] * 1024 for x in range(1024)]` doesn't give you an array, it gives you a list

Comment: If you used `timeit` rather than shoving it in a loop, you'd get `7.4 ms ± 287 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` for the Python list and `11.2 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` for the numpy approach. The timings in your approach are completely flawed because the python `for` loop dominates

Comment: numpy is faster than list. Even you can perform their performance in this link:
https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference . Check using timeit will help you to know more. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running in the exact same machine? I'm getting faster result in `numpy`.

```
In [7]: %%time
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: for i in range(10000):
   ...:     array = np.zeros((1024,1024))
   ...:
CPU times: user 3.33 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 3.33 s
Wall time: 3.32 s

In [8]: %%time
   ...: for i in range(10000):
   ...:     array = [[0.0,] * 1024 for x in range(1024)]
   ...:
CPU times: user 1min 14s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1min 14s
Wall time: 1min 14s
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/994545/5023889) in the `numpy` vs `list` thread also agrees.