# What is the difference between nd.array and array in Python

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I'v met something strange for me. Why I` got different results and why %precision or np.set_printoptions doesn't work
[image]

Comment: What is `array()`?  It's not a builtin python type.

Comment: I didn't see your point, array and np.array are built in different ways, this is just a rounding problem.

Comment: Good place to start [Lists vs. Numpy Arrays - What is the difference?](https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference), [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)