# What is difference b/w Python Range() vs Numpy.arange() function?

Tags: python, numpy

I learned on my web search that numpy.arange take less space than python range function. but i tried
using below it gives me different result.

```
import sys

x = range(1,10000)
print(sys.getsizeof(x))  # --> Output is 48

a = np.arange(1,10000,1,dtype=np.int8)
print(sys.getsizeof(a))  # --> OutPut is 10095
```

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: And do not expect that `getsizeof()` gives you the full memory usage of complex objects.

Comment: You can refer to: https://muddoo.com/tutorials/difference-between-range-vs-arange-in-python/

Comment: @KlausD. range object happen to be quite simple, though. pretty much three int references.

Comment: Have you read the actual documentation for either function? That's always a better starting approach than randomly searching the web

Comment: What's the context?

Answer (score 3):

In PY3, `range` is an object that can generate a sequence of numbers; it is not the actual sequence.  You may need to brush up on some basic Python reading, paying attention to things like lists and generators, and their differences.

```
In [359]: x = range(3)                                                                                 
In [360]: x                                                                                            
Out[360]: range(0, 3)
```

We have use something like `list` or a list comprehension to actually create those numbers:

```
In [361]: list(x)                                                                                      
Out[361]: [0, 1, 2]
In [362]: [i for i in x]                                                                        
Out[362]: [0, 1, 2]
```

A range is often used in a `for i in range(3): print(i)` kind of loop.

`arange` is a `numpy` function that produces a `numpy` array:

```
In [363]: arr = np.arange(3)                                                                           
In [364]: arr                                                                                          
Out[364]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

We can iterate on such an array, but it is slower than [362]:

```
In [365]: [i for i in arr]                                                                             
Out[365]: [0, 1, 2]
```

But for doing things math, the array is much better:

```
In [366]: arr * 10                                                                                     
Out[366]: array([ 0, 10, 20])
```

The array can also be created from the list [361] (and for compatibility with earlier Py2 usage from the `range` itself):

```
In [376]: np.array(list(x))     # np.array(x)                                                                        
Out[376]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

But this is slower than using `arange` directly (that's an implementation detail).

Despite the similarity in names, these shouldn't be seen as simple alternatives. Use `range` in basic Python constructs such as `for` loop and comprehension.  Use `arange` when you need an array.

An important innovation in Python (compared to earlier languages) is that we could iterate directly on a list.  We didn't have to step through indices.  And if we needed indices along with with values we could use `enumerate`:

```
In [378]: alist = ['a','b','c']                                                                        
In [379]: for i in range(3): print(alist[i])   # index iteration                                                        
a
b
c
In [380]: for v in alist: print(v)    # iterate on list directly                                       
a
b
c
In [381]: for i,v in enumerate(alist): print(i,v)    #  index and values                                                  
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Thus you might not see `range` used that much in basic Python code.

Comment: Very useful deep dive. Perhaps also compare `np.array(10*list(range(5)))` with `10*np.array(list(range(5)))` to show how to correctly create an _array-with-math_ from a pre-existing list.

Answer (score 1):

the `range` type constructor creates `range` objects, which represent sequences of integers with a start, stop, and step in a space efficient manner, calculating the values on the fly.

`np.arange` function returns a `numpy.ndarray` object, which is essentially a wrapper around a primitive array. This is a fast and relatively compact representation, compared to if you created a python `list`, so `list(range(N))`, but `range` objects are more space efficient, and indeed, take *constant* space, so for all practical purposes, `range(a)` is the same size as `range(b)` for any integers a, b

As an aside, you should take care interpreting the results of `sys.getsizeof`, you must understand what it is doing. So do not naively compare the size of Python lists and numpy.ndarray, for example.

Perhaps whatever you read was referring to Python 2, where `range` returned a *list*. List objects do require more space than `numpy.ndarray` objects, generally.

Answer (score 1):

*`arange`* store each individual value of the array while *`range`* store only 3 values (start, stop and step). That's the reason *`arange`* is taking more space compared to *`range`*.
As the question is about the size, this will be the answer.

But there are many [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993984/1301710) of using `numpy` array and `arange` than python lists for speed, space and efficiency perspective.