# Increasing the speed of reading a matrix using an array of array

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am trying to read a matrix in python, using the following code:

```
rows = int(input())
columns = int(input())

final = [''] * rows
for i in range(len(final)):
    final[i] = list(input())
```

This is giving me a time limit in the problem, are there faster ways to read a matrix and store it in a form of list of lists in python.

The input is

```
3
3
abc
def
ghi
```

I need to store this as

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Maybe there is a way to do in something like stdin, but I have no idea what that is

Comment: @vnikonov_63 if you would vote up I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Numpy** package, it is faster than the python list. The main difference is about the performance. Numpy data structures perform better in:

- Size: Numpy data structures take less space than the list.
- Performance: They have a need for speed and are faster than lists.
- Functionality: Numpy and Scipy have optimized functions such as linear algebra operations.

For further information Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)