# Matplotlic Color by y-value Plot Draw Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, draw

I want to draw my code part. But I encountered an error. My error is:

[image: The error is in the below]

What I have to do?

Comment: Please don't post code nor error message as image. Please post them as text. Please include a minimal viable reproducible example. Maybe the problem with your code is that you are using a Python list instead of a numpy array? You could try `s = np.array(s)`.

Comment: Please read the top-rated answers at [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists)