# Cracking my head over the usage of tilde in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, negation

I read numerous similar posts about the subject here but still cannot make anything out  of this.

I have this simple list:

```
mask =[False, False, False, False, True, True, False]
```

And am attempting to negate this list via the ~ operator (this is the exercise I have been given). Though:

```
neg_mask = ~mask
```

gives me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-b1d572533400> in <module>
----> 1 neg_mask =~mask

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'
```

Tried on python and ipython 3. Well, according to the instructions this is supposed to work.

Comment: It works on `DataFrame`s not lists. It probably also works on pandas series.

Comment: `~` is not defined for a Python `list`. You have to turn a list into a NumPy array or a Pandas series or DataFrame to be able to use `~`. For example, `~np.array(mask)` returns `array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work with the `~` operator you first need to generate a *DataFrame* like for example:

```
import pandas as pd

mask = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False]
mask = pd.DataFrame(mask, columns=['mask'])
mask = ~mask
print(mask)
```

Output:

```
    mask
0   True
1   True
2   True
3   True
4  False
5  False
6   True
```

If you want directly via the list, do a list comprehension working with `not`:

```
mask = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False]
mask = [not i for i in mask]
print(mask)
```

Output:

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator `~` does not work for a built-in Python `list` but does work for a Pandas `DataFrame`.

```
mask = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False]
df = pd.DataFrame(mask)

~df

#        0
# 0   True
# 1   True
# 2   True
# 3   True
# 4  False
# 5  False
# 6   True
```

Answer (score 0):

Operations on pandas' Series and DataFrames are [vectorized via NumPy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html). You can read about NumPy's benefits over Python's standard data structures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists).

For completion's sake, here is an example of bitwise NOT (~) with just an NDArray.

```py
import numpy as np

mask = np.array([False, False, False, False, True, True, False])
inverted = ~mask

print(mask)
print(inverted)
```

Which prints:

```
[False False False False True True False]
[True True True True False False True]
```